# Docker doesn't map to a different port?

Tags: docker

If I understand the command [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) correctly, `docker run -p 3000:3000 someimage` publishes port 3000 in the container to port 3000 on localhost. I'm testing this with the 'getting-started' node app, and it works as expected.

But I thought that `docker run -p 3000:3001 someimage` would publish what's on port 3000 inside the docker contain to localhost:3001, but instead of seeing the application, the browser shows:

> This site can’t be reached

This seems pretty straight forward, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you publish port, first one is host port witch your pc that currently working on it , and second one is  the container port witch your application is running with , I think you did not run your application with port 3001 inside docker container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first number is the outside port. To map conatiner port 3000 to host port 3001, use `-p 3001:3000`